# Passing javascript variable to new php page

Tags: javascript, php

I've basically have a string a user can input and hit "Send". Then this string variable should be passed to another page that opens. I've tried using session, but it doesn't work (the second page doesn't load). Here's my code:

First page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"myText\">";
    echo "<button onclick=\"submit()\">Submit</button>";

    $_SESSION['userInput'] = $input;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var submit = function() {
        input = document.getElementById("myText").value;
        window.open ('runSecond.php','_self',false);}   
</script>
```

Second page.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $input = $_SESSION['userInput'];
    system('./myPythonScript.py ' $input);
?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$input` in the first page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 1

```
 <?php
        session_start();
        echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"myText\">";
        echo "<button onclick=\"submit()\">Submit</button>";

        $_SESSION['userInput'] = $input;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var submit = function() {
            input = document.getElementById("myText").value;
            window.open ('runSecond.php?userInput=' + input,'_self',false);}   
    </script>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $input = $_GET['userInput'];
    system('./myPythonScript.py ' $input);
?>
```

Comment: Use form and get rid of the javascript code would be better. No?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir using a form is the obvious choice. I don't know his use case so i just fixed his code